# Flutter: unable to find git in path

Tags: windows, git, flutter

When ever I run any command related to flutter in VS Code it returns the following:

```
    'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
     operable program or batch file.
     Error: Unable to find git in your PATH. 
     exit code 1
```

I am on a Windows 10 Home system with Git in the system PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the command from the command line (in the app folder).